# Build Server Xap packaging failed. Missing certificate

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, tfsbuild

We are using TFS build server and when I send my application that uses a code signing certificate I get the above message of "Xap packaging failed. Missing certificate."

I Installed the certificate under my logon and the ad account that visual studio team foundation build service host runs under In the personal certificate store.

Any sugegstion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with TFS, I have experienced similar problems trying to setup CI using TeamCity from JetBrains. I am assuming that you're attempting to sign your assemblies or XAPs in a fashion similar to below:

[image: Figure 1: Signing an assembly using an installed certificate]

If this is true, then the problem you are encountering is that TFS is probably running under the SYSTEM account whereas your code-signing certificate is installed under your account. As such, the SYSTEM account doesn't have access to the certificates installed under your account. Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to solve this problem other then [filing a trouble ticket upstream with Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: The issue is getting the cert in the correct store on the server. I will give you the answer since you directed to msft and they gave me the solution.

Comment: Jim, could you post a link to the answer they gave you? I'd like to see it so I can educate myself on how to do this in the future. Thanks!

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684557/tfs-build-server-with-code-signing-certficate